# How can I share an excel document with my team to edit?

Tags: document-library, excel, collaboration

I would like to know if something is possible and where to start.

Each day, my boss sends out a spreadsheet listing our data entry errors for the previous day. All five of us download the sheet, make our edits, and send it back. She then opens each one individually, copies the parts she needs, and pastes it to her master copy. Our company has blocked Google Documents and requires us to use SharePoint; but my boss doesn't know how to set it up.

Could we:

1. Each have the errors sheet on our desktops, make our changes, and then her master copy on the SharePoint would update from our updates?
2. Each have our own errors sheet on SharePoint (as well as her master copy) and pull the data from ours to hers within the same folder in a Document Library?
3. Each have our own errors sheet on SharePoint, and her master copy would be on her desktop, updating from our SharePoint workbooks?

I've been reading about SharePoint for about 3 hours this evening, and I honestly can't find anyone describing a scenario this simple. If this is possible, just let me know and I'll get right on it!

P.S. I've made workbooks that refer to each other on a networked drive before, I'm hoping there's a way to just "refer" to SharePoint cells the same way, but I gather it's not that simple.

Answer (score 3):

Depends how far down the rabbit hole you want to go...

I'd recommend forgetting about Excel and simply making a new **custom list** in SharePoint.  Create **columns** in that list the correspond to what was in your Excel sheet.  Once that is done, create a **Datasheet view**.  You'll end up with a web page that has something that looks like a spreadsheet on it (it's actually more like an Access table).  You can all edit this simultaneously, keep **versions** and, finally, **export** to Excel.

Comment: Great answer! It depends on how far down my boss will let me go... plus we're migrating to office 365, so i'll be looking into all kinds of stuff. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm not sure if you want to go through the trouble of trying to link workbooks together.

An easy option: **Upload the excel docs into a Document Library**

1. Your boss uploads the current weeks excel document into a document library.
2. You and your coworkers edit the document in SharePoint

Pros: similar workflow to what you have now (still use excel), easier for your boss since she doesn't have to copy + paste everything, excel docs now live in one place (not email!), easy

Cons: you guys have to edit the document one at a time (no simultaneous edits!)

Alternatively, it will be more up front work but @Dan's answer really is the best if you want simultaneous edits.

Comment: Pretty sure Excel 2010 supports simultaneous edits, Word does.

Comment: Oo neato. In SP 2007, it doesn't work when the doc is in SharePoint. Not sure if this works now in 2010?

Comment: Indeed, SP2007 doesn't support simultaneous editing.  SP2010 does in Office 2010 but only if the file version is Office 2007 or better (i.e. *.xlsx)

Comment: I don't think we'll need simultaneous edits, there's only 5 of us so we can probably work out taking turns. Plus our company is small enough that we all use our own home computers so we don't all have the same versions of office and windows, so .xlsx is still unsupported by some of my team

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a shared workbook**
this URL may be help you (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-shared-workbooks-HP005262294.aspx)

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, link only answers is of little help if the link breaks. Instead add some of the main steps to your answer and use the link merely as a source of more detailed information :)

Answer (score 0):

List , Access services is the only solution for your case 
Just copy your excel worksheet and paste it into Acces db as a table then create webform for this tabe finaly share and sync your db file to sharepoint site